# how to make docker logs in java

Tags: java, selenium, docker

I want to create and run docker using docker java client. I want running something like this:

```
docker logs -f selenium-hub
```

How to implement this command on docker-java client? Here is my code so far:

```
result = dockerClient.logContainerCmd(container.getId())
                       .withStdErr(true)
                       .withStdOut(true)
                       .withFollowStream(true)
                       .withTailAll()
                       .exec(logContainerResultCallback);
               try {
                   logContainerResultCallback.awaitCompletion();
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   throw new BaseException(e.getMessage());
               }catch (Exception e){
                   throw new BaseException(e.getMessage());
               }
               break;
```

why it didn't show like docker show?
docker show like

```
"host": null,
"port": 4444,
 "prioritizer": null,
 "capabilityMatcher": "org.openqa.grid.internal.utils.DefaultCapabilityMatcher"

 "throwOnCapabilityNotPresent": true,
 "newSessionWaitTimeout": -1,
 "jettyMaxThreads": -1,
 "nodePolling": 5000,
 "cleanUpCycle": 5000,
 "timeout": 30000,
 "browserTimeout": 0,
 "maxSession": 5,
 "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 30000
```

but it didn't show in java.

please help me. I'm newbie in docker. I want to implement this in java. thanks a lot

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/spotify/docker-client/issues/108